# PHP: Wrong output using IF ELSE statement

Tags: php

Here's my database sample:

```
  **Netname**     **BldgName**                    **Totalduration**
    LRT - 2       Araneta Center - Cubao              09:30:00
    LRT - 2          Legarda                          09:45:00
    LRT - 2           Pureza                          09:50:00
    LRT - 2           Santolan                        10:00:00
    LRT - 2         Recto Station                     09:55:00
```

Then I have a combobox for Duration...

```
Duration
5 s
10 s
15 s
30 s
60 s
```

Here's my code:

```
if(($get_ID == "LRT - 2" || $get_ID == "LRT - 1") && $row[fldTotalDuration] == "10:00:00")
{
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['fldBldgName'];
    echo "&nbsp;<img src='image/full.png' title='Already full'><br>";
}
else if(($get_ID == "LRT - 2" || $get_ID == "LRT - 1")&& $row['fldTotalDuration'] >= "09:55:00" && $row['fldTotalDuration'] <= "10:00:00" && $get_duration >= "6 s" && $get_duration <= "60 s"  )
{
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['fldBldgName'];
    echo "&nbsp;<img src='image/near_full.png' title='Only 5 s left'><br>";
}
else if(($get_ID == "LRT - 2" || $get_ID == "LRT - 1")&& $row['fldTotalDuration'] >= "09:50:00" && $row['fldTotalDuration'] <= "09:54:00" && $get_duration >= "11 s"&& $get_duration <="60 s" )
{
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['fldBldgName'];
    echo "&nbsp;<img src='image/near_full.png' title='Only 10 s left'><br>";
}
else if(($get_ID == "LRT - 2" || $get_ID == "LRT - 1")&& $row['fldTotalDuration'] >= "09:45:00" && $row['fldTotalDuration'] <= "09:49:00" && $get_duration >= "16 s" && $get_duration <= "60 s")
{
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['fldBldgName'];
    echo "&nbsp;<img src='image/warning.png' title='Only 15 s left'><br>";
}
else if(($get_ID == "LRT - 2" || $get_ID == "LRT - 1")&& $row['fldTotalDuration'] >= "09:30:00" && $row['fldTotalDuration'] <= "09:44:00" && $get_duration >= "31 s" && $get_duration <= "60 s")
{
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['fldBldgName'];
    echo "&nbsp;<img src='image/warning.png' title='Only 30 s left'><br>";
}
else if(($get_ID == "LRT - 2" || $get_ID == "LRT - 1")&& $row['fldTotalDuration'] >= "09:00:00" && $row['fldTotalDuration'] <= "09:29:00" && $get_duration > "60 s")
{
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $row['fldBldgName'];
    echo "&nbsp;<img src='image/warning.png' title='Only 60 s left'><br>";
}
```

Sample Scenario:

I choose "5 s" for duration...

Here's the output of my program, :
This one is wrong....
[image]

The output should be..

This one is the correct output:

because I will just add only "5 seconds" in the total duration....the rest duration is working but instead of this one [5 sec]

[image]

Thanks for the help..

Comment: You should post a piece of code as small as possible that we can run on our pc and try to see what is wrong.

Comment: `$someVar >= "60 s` is just going to end in tears: `'10s' > '5s'` evaluates to _false_... when comparing number, make sure to compare _numeric types_, not strings... and _refactor this code_, please... maintaining this is going to make someone cry

Comment: @Veda...Thats already the summary of my code...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem....i put like that "60 s" because thats the output came from dropdown fo duration...Sorry you mean...i should remove the "s" word??

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem/..problem solved!...can you post it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by the OP: the problem lies with the way `$get_duration`'s value is evaluted:

```
$get_duration <= "60 s"
```

for example... comparing strings is always going to be troublesome:

```
var_dump('9s' > '4s');//true
//but:
var_dump('10s' > '5s');//false!
var_dump('9s' > '50s');//true!
```

This is because strings are compared differently:

'9s' > '50s'

Probably best understood if you look at C's way of dealing with strings: '9' => 57 (ASCII), whereas '5' is actually 53, and since 57 > 53, the comparison of the two strings equates to true. especially if you consider `0` is actually 48, but `s` is actually 115. 
Of course, PHP will spot cases where you're actually comparing `'12' > '9'`, and compare the integer vals instead (`12 > 9`). But, to be safe, I personally prefer casting my variables to the right type. That way, I'm sure of what type given variable contains

When comparing numbers, compare the integer/float values, not string representations of them.
Basically, replace all those `"60 s"` string constants with `60`. As the OP mentioned: this solves the problem/.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem...thanks again.. :) and by the way.."var_dump('9s' > '4s');//true" this one, i though we should remove the "s"??

Comment: @user2826499: Yes, but that was just to explain that greater/less than comparisons and strings are dangerous! What you should do, ideally is `(int) $get_duration > 60 ` (compare integers)

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to try and figure out what exactly you are doing here. Just going to recommend using the Switch command, rather than a load of nested if/elseif statements.

If I see that you hard-code the LRT - 2 in there, I assume you could make things better also by formulating your database query differently.